# UINavigationBar not transparent on first load

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a view that needs a transparent `UINavigationBar`. I have some code that does just that. However, when the view first loads, I get the normal white `UINavigationBar`. It's only after I press back and go into the view again, that it's transparent as it should be. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"View will appear");
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Try calling setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate at the end of viewWillAppear.

Comment: try  self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; insted self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;